# Code equivalent of out or reference parameters in Dart

Tags: dart

In Dart, how would I best code the equivalent of an (immutable/value/non-object) **out or reference parameter**?

For example in C#-ish I might code:

```
function void example()
{
  int result = 0;
  if (tryFindResult(anObject, ref result))
    processResult(result);
  else
    processForNoResult();
}

function bool tryFindResult(Object obj, ref int result)
{
  if (obj.Contains("what I'm looking for"))
  {
    result = aValue;
    return true;
  }
  return false;  
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible in Dart. Support for struct value types, ref or val keywords were discussed on the Dart mailing list just like week. Here is a link to the discussion where you should let your desire be known:

https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/topic/misc/iP5TiJMW1F8/discussion

The Dart-way would be:

```
void example() {
  List result = tryFindResult(anObject);
  if (result[0]) {
    processResult(result[1]);
  } else {
    processForNoResult();
  }
}

List tryFindResult(Object obj) {
  if (obj.contains("What I'm looking for")) {
    return [true, aValue];
  }
  return [false, null];
}
```

Comment: This is a fine way of handling the pattern. Minimal excess and fairly readable (just have to stick with a consistent array ordering). I'm new to Dart and just wasn't sure if there were a best practice or non heap+GC way to handle this.

Comment: An alternative would be simply to return the object in question or null and test for null. Or omit adding the boolean to the list and just add the found object and test for an empty list. Or use a closure  tryFindResult(Object obj, Function callMeIfYouFindSomething) { if ... callMeIfYouFindSomething(aValue); ...

Comment: But what if I want to pass a variable into a constructor or method which updates the original instead of calling it by value?

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a tuple package like tuple-2.0.0

add tuple: ^2.0.0
to your pubspec.yaml

then any function can return many typed objects like this:

```
import 'package:tuple/tuple.dart';

Tuple3<int, String, bool?>? returnMany() {
return ok ? Tuple3(5, "OK", null) : null;
}




var str = returnMany().item2;
```

In your case:

```
void example() {
  var result = tryFindResult(anObject);
  if (result.item1) {
    processResult(result.item2!);
  } else {
    processForNoResult();
  }
}

Tuple2<bool, int?> tryFindResult(Object obj) {
  if (obj.contains("What I'm looking for")) {
    return Tuple2(true, aValue);
  }
  return Tuple2(false, null);
}
```

you can throw an exception too when no result.

```
void example() {
  var result = tryFindResult(anObject);
  try {
    processResult(result);
  } on NullException catch(e){
    processForNoResult();
  }
}

int tryFindResult(Object obj) { // throws NullException
  if (obj.contains("What I'm looking for")) {
    return aValue;
  }
  throw NullException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider wrapping in a class. Can be laborious but sometimes it's worth it.

```dart
// hypothetically speaking...
class Example {
    int result;

    bool findResult(MyObject obj) {
        if (obj.Contains("what I'm looking for")) {
            result = aValue;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

void example(MyObject obj) {
    Example e;

    if (e.findResult(obj)) {
        processResult(e.result);
    } else {
        processForNoResult();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of dart support native tuple returns so you can return as many items as you want:

```
void example() {
  final (result, obj) = tryFindResult(anObject);
  if (result) {
    processResult(obj);
  } else {
    processForNoResult();
  }
}

(bool, object?) tryFindResult(Object obj) {
  if (obj.contains("What I'm looking for")) {
    return (true, avalue);
  }
  return (false, null);
}
```