# Create list of unique objects

Tags: dart

I'm trying to fill a List with a unique object of my choosing, which will later be acted on. Is it just me, or is the following unintuitive:

```
class Event {
    void bang()
    {
        type = "bang";
    }

    String type;
}

void main()
{
    var intList= new List<int>.filled( 4, 0 );
    intList[1] = 1;

    var eventList = new List<Event>.filled( 4, new Event() );
    eventList[1].bang();    
}
```

At this point, `intList` looks like `[0, 1, 0, 0]`, while `eventList` has all four slots filled with the same `Event` object, and its `type` Strings all equal "bang".

What I was hoping for was a list of four separate `Event` objects, what is the best way to achieve this?  I can of course build the List in a for loop:

```
var eventList = new List<Event>( 4 );
for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
    events[i] = new Event();
}
```

But this is obviously more code, time consuming and error prone to write. Not to mention potentionally slower on the VM side.

Comment: If you don't think this is the same problem, add a comment. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258267

Comment: It is indeed the same problem, though presented a bit differently so I'll just state that the solution given is to use the `List.generate()` constructor.  Thanks!