# Pass state variable reference to function

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to reuse one function to update different state variables of a `StatefulWidget`. Which state variable gets updated should depend on the variable reference which is passed to the function as a parameter. Here's some example code:

```
class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {
  String stateVariable = 'initial value';

  void update(String variableRef) {
    setState((() {
      variableRef = 'updated value';
    })
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => update(stateVariable),
      child: Text(stateVariable)
    )
  }
}
```

The state is set successfully in the `setState` function, but unfortunately the state change is not represented in the UI, i.e. the `build` function is not called again.

My expectation here would be that the `stateVariable` should be updated since I pass the variable to the `update` function by reference. Is this assumption false?

Do you know a way of passing a state variable by reference so that it can be updated idempotently by a function?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258267/is-there-a-way-to-pass-a-primitive-parameter-by-reference-in-dart

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the assumptions if false. Dart cannot pass variables by reference, all parameters are passed by value. (Object values are actually object references, but that's a separate and unrelated use of the word "reference", and passing an object as a parameter does pass the object reference *by value*).

If you want to pass something that allows the callee to change the value of a variable, you should pass a "setter function":

```
void update(void setVariable(String value)) {
   setState(() {
     setVariable('updated value');
   });
}
...
   update((value) { stateVariable = value; });
```

There is no way to "tear off" a setter, so you have to write the function out.

Answer (score 0):

I accepted the answer of `Irn` and would like to share my solution, which I ended up using.

```dart
Future<String> update() async {
  ... // Do some async stuff here.
  return Future.value('updated value');
}
...
update().then((value) => setState(() { stateVariable = value });
```

It removes the necessity of updating the state in the `update` function. This does not answer my question, but is a more elegant way I believe.