# How do I change a value of a variable in this case?

Tags: dart

I'm a beginner of flutter and dart.
I'm teaching myself very hard these days, and I suddenly noticed there was awkward thing.
I made a function called increase(), which was made to increase the integer input by one.
But I found that didn't work.

I googled it a lot and I could found it's related to something called 'pointer'.
But as you know I'm an appalling stupid, so couldn't get it well.
Now, I just want to know how I increase the value 3 to 4. 
Thank you in advance. I paste my source code below.

```
void main() {
  int a = 3;
  increase(a);
  print(a);
}

increase(int x) {
  x++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because dart is pass by value and not by reference. There are ways around this but for your simple example you can do something like this

```
void main() {
  int a = 3;
  a = increase(a);
  print(a);
}

increase(int x) {
  return ++x;
}
```

also refer to this link for a similar question and other ways to go around it

[Is there a way to pass a primitive parameter by reference in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258267/is-there-a-way-to-pass-a-primitive-parameter-by-reference-in-dart)

Comment: I really appreciate it. Hope you have a nice day!