# I created a copy of an object but when I update it it updates the original

Tags: flutter, dart

Firstly, I have two models like this:

```
class Task {
final int id;
final String title;
final List<User> users;
}

class User {
final int id;
final String name;
}
```

I have the original Task object let call it A, and I make a copy called B so that I can reset B to A if user make a mistake and wants to retrieve the original one. Here is the copy :

```
Task a = Task(
    id:0,
    title: 'Task 1',
    users: [
        User(
            id:1,
            name: 'John',
        ),
    ],
);

Task b = Task(
    id: a.id,
    title: a.title,
    user: List<User>.from(a.users),
);
```

When I update b.id and b.title there is no problems, if I reset my object it come back to a data.

But if I update the user name of user with the id 1 on B, it updates the user on A. I don't understand why ?

Comment: I think, [Is there a way to pass a primitive parameter by reference in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18258267/10157127) answer your question.

Comment: You cannot copy a custom class that way, even less a list of them. You're only copying references which is why you get this result. There is a discussion on how to overcome this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107906/how-can-i-clone-an-object-deep-copy-in-dart

Comment: add `new` in front of user list in b

Comment: new doesn't work and other posts unfortunately doesn't helped me

Comment: @lrsvmb `new` is not necessary and will not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

The scenario you describe is not possible with the code that you've posted.  You claim:

> But if I update the user name of user with the id 1 on B, it updates the user on A.

but your `User` class declaration contains only `final` members of immutable types, so it is not possible to modify a `User` object.  The code you've posted also omits explicit constructors for your classes.

Assuming that you don't actually have `final` members: Your problem is that although `b` is a new `Task` object that copies the members of `a`, it is not a *deep* copy.  `b.users` copies of the `a.users` `List` itself but not the `List` *elements*.  The `a.users` and `b.users` `List`s thus refer to the same `User` objects.

There is no automatic way to make copies (much less deep copies).  You would need to do something like:

```dart
class User {
  int id;
  String name;

  User({required this.id, required this.name});

  User clone() => User(
        id: id,
        name: name,
      );
}

class Task {
  int id;
  String title;
  List<User> users;

  Task({required this.id, required this.title, required this.users});

  Task clone() => Task(
        id: id,
        title: title,
        users: [
          for (var user in users) user.clone(),
        ],
      );
}
```